# Binary Representation of Complex Numbers

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, peano-axioms

Modular arithmetic (MA) has the same axioms as first order [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) (PA) except $\forall x(Sx \neq 0)$ is replaced with $\exists x(Sx=0)$. MA has finite models based on [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). MA is [$\omega$-inconsistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) and all infinite models are [non-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). A number of people have stated that any algebraically closed field (ACF) is a model of MA.

Removing first order induction from the other axioms of MA leaves a weak sub-theory of ring theory. Obviosly, every ACF is a model of ring theory. ACF's satisfy first order induction because they [admit quantifier elimination](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gp351/acf-qe.pdf). I don't pretend to understand the proof. I do know if ACF's are models of MA they must have some amazing properties.

Wikipedia describes the order type of a countable non-standard model of PA. The standard natural numbers are followed by a countably infinite number of copies of structures with the same order type as the integers. These structures are sometimes call Z-blocks. The Z-blocks are dense in that between any two distinct Z-blocks there is another Z-block.

Models of MA don't really have an order type because they can't be well ordered. But they do have some order. Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a ring $\mathbb{Z} /x \mathbb{Z}$ where $x$ is a non-standard natural number in some countable non-standard model of PA. $\mathbb{M}$ does have a [cyclic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order). This cyclic order can be "cut" to form a linear order. We can order each element of $\mathbb{M}$: 0 < 1 < ... < x-2 < x-1. It seems reasonable this linear order would have a similar order type as the countable non-standard model of PA. If so, a countably infinite model of MA would be a ring with a countably infinite number of Z-blocks dense in the rationals.

The [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), $\mathbb{A}$, are a countably infinite ACF. Does $\mathbb{A}$ have the structure I describe above? Is $\mathbb{A}$ isomorphic to some ring $\mathbb{Z} /x \mathbb{Z}$ where $x$ is a countable non-standard natural number? There are a number of ways I can ask this question. I know little about ring theory, but I think I am asking if an ACF can have a non-standard (and non-zero) characteristic.

$\forall x(Sx=x+S0)$ is a theorem of both MA and PA. Since we are talking about complex numbers, this give us $\forall x (Sx = x +(1.0... + 0.0... \cdot \sqrt{-1}))$. Notice the imaginary part of $S0 = (1.0... + 0.0... \cdot \sqrt{-1})$ is $0$ and no matter how many times we apply successor to $(0.0... 
+ 0.0... \cdot \sqrt{-1})$ the imaginary part will be $0.0...$. Assume we apply successor to $0 \sqrt{-1}$ times. We must get $(\sqrt{-1} + 0.0... \cdot \sqrt{-1})$. $\sqrt{-1}$ has to be like any other hyper-integer. It must be reachable from $0$ with successor.

In both MA and PA every number is the sum of distinct powers of 2. Binary representations are not unique in MA. For example, $2^3 \equiv 2^1+2^0 \equiv 3 \bmod 5$. Does $\sqrt{-1}$ have a binary representation in $\mathbb{A}$? I can already prove every ACF has [an odd number of elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119375/even-xor-odd-infinities) which means $\sqrt{-1}$ must be even. If $\sqrt{-1}$ has a binary expansion then it is equivalent to some hyper-integer, $x$. The size of the field would be $x^2+1$.

---

Response to Lawrence Wong

I am not sure how to answer your question. The short answer is successor is a total function. The way it was explained to me is $n=S_n(0)$ defines $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ where $S_n(0)$ means applying successor to $0$ $n$ times. Just like "$3 = SSS0$". Outside of the model, we know if $t$ is a non-standard natural number larger than any standard natural number then $S_t(0)$ will require us to apply successor a countably infinite number of times. Inside the model, $t$ is just another "finite" natural number and must be reachable from $0$ with a "finite" number of applications of successor.

Assume $t$ is not reachable from $0$ by successor. Then induction fails. I could define a predicate true for all successors of $0$ and false for $t$.

Comment: Hi, this was the worry in [one of my previous comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556547/).  Anyway, what do you mean by "$\sqrt{-1}$ is reachable from 0 with successor"?

Comment: @Lawrence Wong: I realize I could be completely wrong. The Peano with Top you described earlier is probably a counter example to my argument. Any elaboration of your worries would be welcome.

Comment: In PA, one can express $x=0+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{$y$ times}}$ as a first-order formula with free variables $x$ and $y$ using some coding. I am not sure whether this can be done in MA because I don't know how much coding power MA has. As a result, it is not clear to me how one can prove $\forall x\ \exists y\ (x=0+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{$y$ times}})$ in MA using first-order induction.

Comment: MA can encode any "finite" set of natural numbers as long as each member of the set is less than log2(|M|). Not sure how to take log2 of the size of complex numbers, but an uncountable model of MA should be able to encode any finite set of standard natural numbers. I would be interested in any first order proof of $x = 0 + 1 + ... +1$. This seems to come up in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Induction is very weak in MA. Any statement true in every model must be true in the smallest model, the [trivial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring). Even $0=1$ is independent of the axioms of MA.

Comment: To show $\forall x\ \exists y\ (x=0+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{$y$ times}})$ by induction, essentially one needs to code the sequence $\langle0,1,2,\ldots,x\rangle$ uniformly in $x$, and in particular, independently of whether $x$ is standard or not. As far as I can understand, the problem with Peano-with-Top is that there is a maximum $x$ for which $2^x$ exists, so that even if we can code $\langle0,1,2,\ldots,x\rangle$, we cannot code $\langle0,1,2,\ldots,x,x+1\rangle$ because $2^{x+1}$ does not exist. So the induction step breaks down in this situation.

Comment: MA can encode $x$ up to $log_2(|M|)$ which is less than $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: How would you define an order on the algebraic numbers (or the complex numbers)?

Comment: I am not sure I can. I just assumed $log_2(x) < \sqrt{x}$. I have some ideas. I am looking at the [weak pigeonhole theorem](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Papers/pigeon-stoc.pdf).