# Recursive non-standard models?

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

Any algebraically closed field (ACF) is a model of Modular Arithmetic (MA). MA has the same axioms as first order [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) except $\forall x(Sx \neq 0)$ is replaced with $\exists x(Sx=0)$. MA is [$\omega$-inconsistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) and all infinite models are [non-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). This means any ACF can be a non-standard model of arithmetic.

Are addition and multiplication recursive in an ACF? If so, how would such a model avoid [Tennenbaum's theorem](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/papers/tennenbaum/tennenbaum)? I know there are weak theories with recursive non-standard models, but MA is not a weak theory.

---

Response to tomasz:

First a quick proof every infinite model of MA is non-standard. Assume $S(n)=0$ and $n$ is a standard natural number. Then the model is finite. $-1$ must be non-standard in any infinite model of MA.

I have been told any algebraically closed field (ACF) is a model of MA. I have yet to prove otherwise. It is clear any ACF satisfies the axioms of MA without induction. ACF's satisfy first order induction because they [admit quantifier elimination](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gp351/acf-qe.pdf). I don't pretend to understand the proof or really understand why quantifier elimination implies first order induction is valid. I assume it has something to do with "finiteness". The authors go to a lot of trouble to prove "root diagrams" are definable.

The answer to your first question is yes. Both $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are models of MA. I am not sure what you mean about a field of prime characteristic. A model of MA does not have to be a field. I know practically nothing about ring theory, but I thought all ACF's have characteristic $0$. I recently posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593667/binary-representation-of-complex-numbers) about this.

Your second question is tougher and one of the reasons I posted this question. Tennenbaum's theorem does apply to non-standard models of PA. Tennenbaum's theorem is a proof by contradiction. I couldn't find a simple description of it online. I will try to describe the proof without mangling it too much. Any corrections are welcome.

Tennenbaum showed that if either addition or multiplication is recursive in a non-standard model of PA then we can recursively separate two recursively inseparable sets. Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the set of standard natural numbers encoding a Turing machine (TM) that halts on blank input. $\mathbb{H}$ is recursively enumerable and is not recursively separable from the set of numbers representing TM's that don't halt. Let $y=F(n)$ mean $y$ encodes the first $n$ members of $\mathbb{H}$. There are lots of way we can encode members of $\mathbb{H}$. We could define a polynomial $(x-h_1)(x-h_2)...(x-h_n)$. We could use the binary representation of a number such that $2^h$ is true in the representation only if $h \in \mathbb{H}$. [Robinson's overspill lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overspill) says if $\exists y (y=F(n))$ is true for all standard natural numbers there must exist a non-standard $n$ for which it is true. Let $y^* = F(n^*)$ be true. We can use the binary expansion of $y^*$ to recursively separate members of $\mathbb{H}$ from representations of non-halting TM's. From this we conclude addition and multiplication are not recursive in non-standard models of PA.

My question is why doesn't this same argument apply to MA? Assume $\mathbb{C}$ is a model of MA. What prevents me from encoding $\mathbb{H}$ using the binary representation of a real number, $r^*$? If I can finitely specify $r^*$ as the $k^{th}$ root of a polynomial of degree $n$, it seems I could recursively determine the elements of  $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Are the complex numbers a model of MA? I assume you interptet $Sx$ a s $x+1$. In that case, you want the field to be of a prime characteristic.

Comment: Also, how does the Tennenbaum's theorem relate to this? As far as I can see (according to Wikipedia and the site you linked), it's a theorem about models of PA, not MA.

Comment: In a ACF of positive characteristic $p$, induction fails on the formula $\phi(n) := n^p = n$

Comment: @mercio That is interesting. Could you expand on this? I have been told the 2-adic numbers are a model of MA. How do you define $p$ in a field of characteristic $p$?

Comment: The 2-adics aren't algebraically closed and are a field of characteristic 0 so... idk. Your link says that ACF0 (so ACF with the axioms 1<>0, 2<>0, 3<>0, ....) has quantifier elimination, but it doesn't say anything for ACF. Furthermore, iirc ACF0 is complete and decidable, so the algebraic closure of the 2-adics, for example, is isomorphic to C. It doesn't mean that C is a model of Peano arithmetic so you can't use it to get nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic.

Comment: You don't need to define p. The algebraic closure of F2 is not a model of "(0^2=0 and forall n, (n²=n implies (n+1)²=n+1)) implies (forall n, n²=n)" (because the lefthand is true and the righthand is false), so it is not a model of MA.